# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Vector cannot be cast to My Class

Tags: java, class, for-loop, foreach

im using a for with a query to obtain some rows and finally add all of these rows into one Arraylist of one class. But i receive the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Vector cannot be cast to com.dominion.procop.agr.util.AGRSalvaguardasInforme
    at (pathofmyclass).mostrarInformeActivosAGR(AGRInformes.java:1130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

the lines are these (The marked with $ is the `AGRInformes.java:1130`) :

```
            for (int i = 0; i < InformeAmenazasAGR.size()-1; i++) {
                String Amenaza = InformeAmenazasAGR.get(i).toString();
                Amenaza = Amenaza.substring(1,3);
                List<AGRSalvaguardasInforme> resultadoQuery = (List<AGRSalvaguardasInforme>) manager.SalvaguardaPorAmenaza(Amenaza);

                if(!resultadoQuery.isEmpty() ){                 
$                   for (AGRSalvaguardasInforme salvaguardaExtraida : resultadoQuery) {
                        InformeSalvaguardasAGR.add(salvaguardaExtraida);
                    }
                }                           
            }
```

And this is the `manager.SalvaguardaPorAmenaza()` method (Query and return the objects):

```
public List<AGRSalvaguardasInforme> SalvaguardaPorAmenaza(String idAmenaza) {
    // SALVAGUARDAS POR ID_AMENAZA
        int dimension = 0;
        String consulta = "";   
        if(dimension!=0){   
            consulta = "SELECT COALESCE(MFT.ID_AMENAZA, MFA.ID_AMENAZA) as ID_AMENAZA, SAL.ID_SALVAGUARDA, SAL.DENOMINACION, SAL.DESCRIPCION, SAL.EFICACIA FROM AGR_SALVAGUARDAS SAL LEFT JOIN AGR_MIT_FREC_TIPO MFT "
                     + " ON SAL.ID_SALVAGUARDA = MFT.ID_SALVAGUARDA AND MFT.ID_AMENAZA = "+idAmenaza+" "
                     + " LEFT JOIN AGR_MIT_FREC_ACT MFA "
                     + " ON SAL.ID_SALVAGUARDA = MFA.ID_SALVAGUARDA AND MFA.ID_AMENAZA = "+idAmenaza+" "
                     + " WHERE MFT.ID_SALVAGUARDA IS NOT NULL OR MFA.ID_SALVAGUARDA IS NOT NULL GROUP BY SAL.ID_SALVAGUARDA, SAL.DENOMINACION, SAL.DESCRIPCION, SAL.EFICACIA, MFT.ID_AMENAZA, MFA.ID_AMENAZA";
        }else{
            consulta = "SELECT COALESCE(MFT.ID_AMENAZA, MFA.ID_AMENAZA) as ID_AMENAZA, SAL.ID_SALVAGUARDA, SAL.DENOMINACION, SAL.DESCRIPCION, SAL.EFICACIA FROM AGR_SALVAGUARDAS SAL LEFT JOIN AGR_MIT_FREC_TIPO MFT "
                     + " ON SAL.ID_SALVAGUARDA = MFT.ID_SALVAGUARDA AND MFT.ID_AMENAZA = "+idAmenaza+" "
                     + " LEFT JOIN AGR_MIT_FREC_ACT MFA "
                     + " ON SAL.ID_SALVAGUARDA = MFA.ID_SALVAGUARDA AND MFA.ID_AMENAZA = "+idAmenaza+" "
                     + " WHERE MFT.ID_SALVAGUARDA IS NOT NULL OR MFA.ID_SALVAGUARDA IS NOT NULL GROUP BY SAL.ID_SALVAGUARDA, SAL.DENOMINACION, SAL.DESCRIPCION, SAL.EFICACIA, MFT.ID_AMENAZA, MFA.ID_AMENAZA";
                }
            Query q = dao.createNativeQuery(consulta);
            List<AGRSalvaguardasInforme> resultado = q.getResultList();

            return resultado;
        }
```

Why appears this error and how i can manage correctly?.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you post code, please point with a comment the exact line (in this case line 1130 of AGRInformes) where you get the error.

Comment: In which line is the error?

Comment: Ah thank God that I know which line throws that exception...

Comment: Sorry, i forgot. The line is marked with $ symbol.

Comment: I don't see it anywehre... It would be much simpler if you would write something like: Hey guys, the exception is thrown in this line `hereIsSomePartOfYourCode.thatActuallyThrows(Exception);`

Comment: `for (AGRSalvaguardasInforme salvaguardaExtraida : resultadoQuery) {` in this line (i update the post)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem 1

Naming is mess, please follow java naming convention.

### Problem 2

```
for (int i = 0; i < InformeAmenazasAGR.size()-1; i++) {
```

in this way, the last element of `List:InformeAmenazasAGR` would never be read.

### Problem 3

```
 for (int i = 0; i < InformeAmenazasAGR.size()-1; i++) {
              ...
                        InformeSalvaguardasAGR.add(salvaguardaExtraida);
                 
                ...                           
            }
```

You are adding element to a list within the for looping. It will lead to unpredictable consequence. If you need do that, use `Iterator`.

### Problem 4

If you used "NativeQuery" (I guess jpa?) `.getResultList()`, you got a `List<Object[]>`,  You cannot expect the query to give you a `List<YourClass>`. You have to go into the result, and do the work by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like

```
     Query q = dao.createNativeQuery(consulta);
     List<AGRSalvaguardasInforme> resultado = q.getResultList();
```

it is not really returning a List of AGRSalvaguardasInforme but a List of Vector. Is Query class yours? You can use debugger to see what is the real type of the elements inside the "resultado" list at runtime.

**Note:** Generic information is lost at runtime due erasure. So there is no runtime check of the types of the elements contained in the collection. The issue is when you start iterating it and expecting each element to be a concrete type they are not.

This:

```
for (AGRSalvaguardasInforme salvaguardaExtraida : resultadoQuery) {
   InformeSalvaguardasAGR.add(salvaguardaExtraida);
}
```

Is just a code sugar for :

```
for (Iterator it : resultadoQuery.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
   AGRSalvaguardasInforme  salvaguardaExtraida = (AGRSalvaguardasInforme) it.next();
   InformeSalvaguardasAGR.add(salvaguardaExtraida);
}
```

So the cast **is** implicitly there (and that cast is the one throwing ClassCastException at runtime for the reasons I mentioned above)

Comment: Exactly, in debugger i see that resultadoQuery is a return of Vector<E>. How i can extract the rows from resultadoQuery? Thank you.

Comment: Hmm but shouldn't there be compiler error on line `List<AGRSalvaguardasInforme> resultado = q.getResultList();` as there is no explicit casting of result?

Comment: It depends on the type signature of `q.getResultList()`. If it returns just raw `List` you will get just a warning, if it returns `<T> List<T>` then type inference will assume T is whatever you said on the left side of the assignment and no type error.